# How to out put pi symbol in dev c++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "pi symbol";
getch();
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I have to output a pi symbol in dev c++.
I am searching for it since many days please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output unicode symbol π and ≈ in c++ win32 console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376219/output-unicode-symbol-%cf%80-and-%e2%89%88-in-c-win32-console-application)

Comment: `cout << "\u03C0" << endl;`

Answer (score 1):

To display pi using devcpp you need the unicode for it (as p-a-o-l-o has written in a comment \u03C0). What's more you should use [wide characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character) and set mode of standard output.
Here is the working solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <wchar.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), 0x10000);
    wchar_t *pi = L"\u03C0";
    wcout<<pi;
    cout<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wide characters? I find your lack of UTF-8 disturbing.