# How to key-in UTF8 char and transfer into byte array?

Tags: c++

I'm using VS2010 C++ Win32 console application

I want user that can key-in some UTF8 char and transfer to byte array(which is like: `unsigned char utf8_keyin[10];`)

so if user key in `你好` that can store in `utf8_keyin[4]` as `60,4F,7D,59`.

if user key in `hello` that can store in `utf8_keyin[5]` as `68,65,6C,6C,6F`.

I try two plans

A plan:

```
wstring Ctemp;
wcin >> Ctemp; // if user key in "你好", it will store as "??" in Ctemp
```

B plan:

```
Microsoft::VisualBasic::Interaction::InputBox(...) 
// I have no idea what to do next since the return is basic_string
```

Any idea?

Comment: Does the device you are typing into (Win32 console) accept `utf-8`?

Comment: I seriously doubt that there will be actual question marks (`"?"`) in `Ctemp`... the problem here is that you need to get the input device, your program, and your output device to agree on the same encoding. And once you got your `wstring` input in `Ctemp`, you need to convert it from that encoding to UTF-8. All in all, unclear what you're asking / too broad, I am afraid...

Comment: @Galik I can paste or typing other language word into console app for wcin

Comment: @DevSolar  my application is for normal people like my mom, so only the simplest way like typing and pasting words are prefer, not sure what is device meaing in your comment

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38160929/reading-utf-8-from-stdin-using-fgets-on-windows OR perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376219/output-unicode-symbol-%CF%80-and-%E2%89%88-in-c-win32-console-application

Comment: @DaveG: There are three programs involved in your little conundrum here: The input device (e.g. the terminal), your program, and your output device (e.g. your terminal again, or your editor). Each of these have a locale setting that defines the encoding they work with. If you see "`??`" in `Ctemp` after you typed `你好`, these three settings do not agree with each other. This is a configuration problem, not a programming problem. (The programming problem would be the conversion of `wstring` in {some encoding} to UTF-8.) As your question mingles all this together, I voted to close as "too broad".

Comment: Start slowly, and with little steps. Write a program that writes a UTF-8 string to `cout`, check that it works (or fix your output settings). Write a program that writes a `wstring` (UTF-16 / UTF-32 depending on platform) to `wcout`, check that it works (or fix your output settings). Then the same for input -- make sure your *environment* works correctly. Then your question will be reduced to "how do I convert UTF-16/UTF-32 `wstring` to UTF-8?", which is simple to answer (and has been answered here before).